# .net mvc many to many What to POST

Tags: .net, entity-framework, many-to-many

I am trying to realize a many to many context. A Product can be made from different materials and has a different price for those materials:

Here is the product.cs:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    public partial class Product
    {
        public Product()
        {
            this.ProductMaterials = new HashSet<ProductMaterial>();
        }
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DisplayName("Product name"),
          Required(ErrorMessage = "Product Name is required"),
          StringLength(100)]
        public string Name { get; set; }
        [Required]
        public virtual ICollection<ProductMaterial> ProductMaterials { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the ProductMaterials.cs:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class ProductMaterial
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int ProductId { get; set; }
        public int MaterialId { get; set; }
        public string PriceOffset { get; set; }

        public virtual Material Material { get; set; }
        public virtual Product Product { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And the Material.cs:

```
namespace test.Models
{
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;

    public partial class Material
    {
        public Material()
        {
            this.ProductMaterials = new HashSet<ProductMaterial>();
        }

        public int Id { get; set; }
        [Required,DisplayName("Material"),
          StringLength(100)]
        public string Mat { get; set; }
        [DefaultValue(0), Required]
        public decimal PriceOffset { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<ProductMaterial> ProductMaterials { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Now trying to add the right information in the context so an object can be created from a form, trying to make this as simple as possible to understand this in small steps.

the testContext.cs has the following:

using System.Data.Entity;

```
namespace test.Models
{
    public class testContext : DbContext
    {
System.Data.Entity.DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<test.Models.testContext>());
        public testContext() : base("name=testContext")
        {
        }
        public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Manufacturer> Manufacturers { get; set; }
        public DbSet<ProductMaterial> ProductMaterials { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Material> Materials { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
            .HasMany(c => c.ProductMaterials);
        }    
    }
}
```

This is the extra data I POST:

```
<input type="text" value="1" name="ProductId">
<input type="text" value="1" name="MaterialId">
<input type="text" value="0" name="PriceOffset">
```

When I set a breakpoint in the controller I see a Product object is created with 0 ProductMaterials objects.

Not sure if this is the right way to do it and I see in the example code I downloaded that updating will be far more complicated.

Comment: What's the question exactly? What do you need to put in the HTML? We can't design a whole UI for you on here!

Comment: Nope, just what input to POST to the Create controller

Comment: And what is the Create action supposed to do? Create a new product with one material? Or with many materials? Or create a new `ProductMaterial` relationship for an existing product and material?

Comment: I'm sorry, thought that the input boxes were self explanatory; it's supposed to link one or many existing Material(s) to a product.

Answer (score 0):

Giving up on how to create a new product with Materials added. Got it to work for edit product.

Added a route in global.asax.cs:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "Materials For Product", // Route name
        "Materials/{action}/{ProductId}/{MaterialId}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "ProductMaterial", action = "Index",
              ProductId = UrlParameter.Optional,
              MaterialId = UrlParameter.Optional
        } // Parameter defaults
    );
```

Changed the Index, create and delete in the ProductMaterialController.cs

```
public ViewResult Index(int ProductId)
{
    var productmaterialss = db.ProductMaterials.Include(p => p.Material).Include(p => p.Product).Where(
        p => p.ProductId == ProductId);
    Product pr = db.Products.Find(ProductId);
    ViewData["ProductId"] = ProductId;
    ViewData["ProductName"] = pr.Name;
    return View(productcolors.ToList());
}
public ActionResult Create(int ProductId)
{
    Product p = db.Products.Where(i => i.Id == ProductId).Single();
    ViewBag.MaterialId = new SelectList(db.Materials, "Id", "Mat");
    ViewData["ProductName"] = p.Name;
    ViewData["ProductId"] = p.Id;
    return View();
}
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Create(ProductMaterial productmaterial)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        db.ProductMaterials.Add(productmaterial);
        db.SaveChanges();
        return RedirectToAction("Index/"+productmaterial.ProductId);
    }
    Product p = db.Products.Where(i => i.Id == productmaterial.ProductId).Single();
    ViewBag.MaterialId = new SelectList(db.Materials, "Id", "Mat");
    ViewData["ProductName"] = p.Name;
    ViewData["ProductId"] = p.Id;
    return View();
}
[HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(int id)
{
    ProductMaterial productmaterial = db.ProductMaterials.Find(id);
    int ProductId = productcolor.ProductId;
    db.ProductMaterials.Remove(productmaterial);
    db.SaveChanges();
    return RedirectToAction("Index/"+ProductId);
}
```

Changed edit view of Product to open a model dialog with the ProductMaterial view and changed all the ProductMaterial views (only index and delete because the other are not used) to not include template and show product name.

Added script to Product to open the Modal and attached event listeners on all links and forms to ajax submit the needed info and reset the innerHTML of the modal dialog with the response.